# Telecommunications Spending Data

Tags: data-request, statistics

I wasn't 100% sure if this was the right community to ask this in, this seemed the most appropriate.
Is there a database or source where I can find how much businesses spend on their Telecommunications budget. I work for a Telecom company and am trying to do data analysis for network planning. I apologize if this isn't the right location.

Comment: If you can't find your answer here then you might have more luck at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/